Microsoft Graph API Sharepoint List: Creating Nested Items
I'm using Microsoft Graph API to interact with a sharepoint list. I use this endpoint for creating new entries (items):
POST /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items

With a body so I can specify the values of each field.
My problem is: i have entries of ContentType: item and folder. The endpoint above only create entries in the top level but I want to be able to create entries inside a folder also. Is there anyway for doing that by the graph api? I already know it can be done by the Sharepoint REST API but I'm not using that in my app right now.
I've already tried adding some other key value pairs for the body like the webUrl but it doesn't work.

@devlincarnate unfortunately that's for sharepoint drive not lists

I retracted it.

What's the type of the SharePoint list? The value of list/template property when you call GET /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}

@user2250152
genericList
